# C++ build task throws "undefined reference to" error on build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build, mingw

When I try to run this code the build fails any ideas how i can fix this? I think i have downloaded the MinGw compiler correctly. Sorry for any newbie mistakes just started learning c++ from python.

main.cpp code

```
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

task.json

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Error code:

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g "C:\Users\{__pathToFile__}\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\{__pathToFile__}\main.exe"
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(setargv.o):(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x736): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x7a4): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x86f): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xcab): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0xcf2): more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `__emutls_get_address'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `__emutls_get_address'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `__emutls_get_address'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `__emutls_get_address'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `__emutls_get_address'
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0x3d8): more undefined references to `__emutls_get_address' follow
C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: /mingw/lib/libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s)
```

Comment: It seems like your MinGW installation is incomplete.

Comment: It's also very old. My advice is to do what VSCode tells you and install msys2 and use that to install MinGW: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Can you explain to me what is missing? I have download the c++ compiler from the  MinGw installation manager. Do i need to do something else?

Comment: I am aware it is old. My uni asked us to use this for some reason i can't really upgrade.

Comment: It's so old it doesn't even support anything from the (now rather old) C++11 standard. Whatever dialect your university teaches you, there's so much missing from modern C++ that will make your life as a C++ programmer much easier and simpler. If you follow it blindly and don't learn for yourself, not very many would want to hire you as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Weren't all these fancy GUI IDEs and editors, like VSCode, with their pretty dialogs and buttons, supposed to make things easier, to avoid all these yucky `Makefile`s and shell commands? You mean that I must concoct some magic incantation in the form of a convoluted JSON configuration file, to get basic functionality right? That's a darn shame, isn't it? After reading `make`s man page, as lengthy as it is, with plenty of examples, it's always pretty straightofrward for me to simply push `F5` in emacs, and get everything built.

Comment: That version of MinGW really is too old. If you don't have permissions to install anything you can still use the standalone downloads from https://winlibs.com/ to run the latest GCC/MinGW-w64.